# Installing on VirtualBox from a Bootable CD

Tags: installation, boot, windows, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu Bootable Installation CD.

How to install from the CD to a VirtualBox on Windows after creating a virtual machine as described [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox).

The link mentions about downloading Ubuntu disk image (iso file), but I would like to skip this step as I have a bootable CD already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can I suggest, put your bootable Ubuntu disk into your CD/DVD drive.

At the point where you attach the ISO image as per the instructions, choose the drop-down to select the CD/DVD drive on your Windows box.

Start  the Virtual Guest, it will then boot using the disk in your CD/DVD drive.